# UIActivityIndicatorView freeze

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsurlconnection, uiactivityindicatorview

i have this function which call a function to check CMS for info. but the UIActivityIndicatorView freeze till the check is completed. not sure why.

EDIT: one thing funny, i commented out the performselector. the UIActivityIndicatorView still freezed. until i tapped my back button then it started to spin....

i'm using storyboard, iOS 5

```
-(void)showLoading
{
    [activity startAnimating];
    //loading is a label to show "File Loading"
    loading.alpha =1;
    //is a label to show a 0.3 alpha of the label
    blackOverlay.hidden =0;
    [self performSelector:@selector(updateFromInternet:) withObject:@"a" afterDelay:2];  

    //[self updateFromInternet:@"a"];
}

-(void)updateFromInternet:(NSString *)urlStr

{   

    NSString *URLString = @"http://sites.google.com/site/iphonesdktutorials/xml/Books.xml";
    NSURL *updateDataURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];    

    NSMutableURLRequest *WPXMLFetchRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:updateDataURL];

    self.receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
    self.updateConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:WPXMLFetchRequest delegate:self];

    NSLog(@"Checking update at : %@", updateDataURL);

    //[self.updateConnection cancel];
}



-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    ////NSlog(@"Receiving data");
    [self.receivedData appendData:data];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    ////NSlog(@"Failed to receive data");
    self.receivedData = nil;
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    ////NSlog(@"Received response from data");
    [self.receivedData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    NSString *data=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:self.receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"data %@",data);

    NSError *parseError = nil;
    //NSDictionary *xmlDict = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLData:self.receivedData error:&parseError];
    self.receivedDict = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLData:self.receivedData error:&parseError];

    [self showDataOnScrollView];
}
```

Comment: Did the `activity` start and then freeze or just stayed frozen?

Comment: it jus freeze there, after updateFromInternet got called it started

Comment: What's the meaning of the comment referring to a background thread?  You shouldn't be using `UIKit` objects from anything other than the main thread.  However you haven't shown any threading code.  Is the threading code elsewhere, or are you referring to the `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: as a background thread (it isn't)?

Comment: sorry, that was the wrong comment. yes i commented out performselector. the activity still not runing

Comment: did you implement the [NSURLConnectionDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSURLConnectionDelegate) and how?

Comment: yes i did implement NSURLConnectionDelegate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should delay the "heavy" function a bit and let the Activity Indicator fire.
try adding a 2.0 and not 2 to your delay (I would use a much smaller value - say 0.3)

```
[self performSelector:@selector(updateFromInternet:) withObject:@"a" afterDelay:0.3];
```

if this does not solve's your problem you should look (or post) the code related to the extra stuff you have in your code like : loading.alpha =1; and blackOverlay.hidden =0; which I assume are elements added to the Activity Indicator